# Does work done in a capacitor in moving a charge or increasing potential difference always twice the potential energy stored?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential-energy, capacitance

On doing calculations like this:

Work done in moving a charge across a potential difference = $(CV)V$  = $CV^2$

Potential energy increased = $(1/2)CV^2$

From this work done is twice the potential energy stored.

So my question is, is this true always or is it valid for some conditions only? (if the calculation is true)

Also does can we increase potential keeping the charge same and is work also done and is it related to potential energy in the same way.

Please guide me over this topic.

Answer (score 0):

> work done in moving a charge across a potential difference = () = 2

This calculation is not correct. It should be $dW= (C \ dV) V$. Then $$W = \int_{v_0}^{v_f} CV \ dV$$ which for $v_0=0$ and $v_f=V$ gives the $\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ expression

So the work done on the capacitor is equal to the energy stored in the capacitor, as must be the case for energy conservation. What can happen is that the energy supplied by a battery can be greater than the energy in the capacitor, eg if half of the energy is dumped into a resistor.

Comment: in the first line you said that $W=CV^2$ while later you said that $W=1/2 CV^2$ ......... my teacher solved it like, since charge flowing is $CV$ therefore using the formula $W=QV$  work done is $CV^2$ , he also said that only half the energy is stored as potential energy and the rest is lost, even if wires are used...

Comment: @Bunnypink said “in the first line you said that =2”. I said no such thing. Please do not misquote me. If your teacher solved it that way then your teacher is wrong because V across a capacitor is not constant while it is being charged. That means that it takes less work to store the first electron than it does to store the last electron.

Comment: As Dale points out, the average voltage (when charging from zero) is half of the final voltage. (No energy is lost.)

Comment: @R.W. Bird So according to you no energy is lost while work is done in moving a charge across a potential difference

Comment: Positive work done moving a charge across an electric field goes into potential energy.

Comment: @R.W. Bird that means energy isn't wasted?

Comment: I would say that energy that goes into capacitors or inductors is not wasted. Only energy that goes into resistors is wasted

Comment: In an ideal undamped LC circuit the capacitor can be repeatedly charged and discharged with no loss of energy.

Comment: Yes, and when charging a capacitor in an RC circuit there is a loss of 1/2 of the energy, meaning that 1/2 of the energy goes to the capacitor (and is not lost) and the other 1/2 of the energy goes to the resistor (and is lost). Interestingly, this is independent of the value of the resistor or capacitor.